# I am running the following query to create trigger for checking age from date_of_birth in phpmyadmin, but its not working

Tags: mysql, triggers

```
CREATE
    TRIGGER women_age_check
    BEFORE INSERT
    ON women FOR EACH ROW
   BEGIN
   IF (TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,:new.date_of_birth,CURDATE()) < 18)
          THEN
               CALL `'Age must be greater than 18'`; 

    END IF; 
END;
```

I am getting either syntax error or error 1303 - Can't create a PROCEDURE from within another stored routine

Comment: signal sqlstate 'Age less than 18'; I am using this instead of CALL.

Comment: I want to prevent the insert from happening if this condition is satisfied

Comment: I am sorry,  what does that mean?

Comment: CREATE TRIGGER women_age_check
BEFORE INSERT ON women 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, NEW.date_of_birth, CURRENT_DATE) < 18 THEN
     SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
     SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Age less than 18';
    END IF;
END

Comment: I changed the code, now error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 7